# Usage of mount_nodev inside rootfs_mount

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to understand how kernel mounting the filesystem. While checking the source, I have observed that `do_mounts.c` file having the source related to mounting (rootfs file system is registered inside `init_rootfs()`).

`rootfs_mount()` function was called by `start_kernel()` initially, I could not able to understand the usage of `mount_nodev()` inside `rootfs_mount()`. Could you please help me to understand the logic behind calling `rootfs_mount()` from `start_kernel()`, as it is not mounting any filesystem.

Actual filesystem mounting is initiated by calling `mount_nfs_root()` or `mount_block_root()` functions from `kernel_init()`, please tell me if my understanding is different.

Comment: Which kernel version did you check?

Comment: I was using 3.12 and 3.14 Linux kernel versions.

Comment: I see no call to `rootfs_mount()` in [`start_kernel()`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.14.79/source/init/main.c#L479).

Comment: I think it follows "start_kernel ----> vfs_caches_init ----> mnt_init ----> init_mount_tree ----> vfs_kern_mount ----> mount_fs ----> rootfs_mount". you can use dump_stack to check.

Comment: That's right, here `type->mount` in [`mount_fs()`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.14.79/source/fs/super.c#L1081) is `rootfs_mount` (from [`rootfs_fs_type`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.14.79/source/init/do_mounts.c#L612)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could not able to understand the usage of `mount_nodev()`
>   inside `rootfs_mount()`. Could you please help me to
>   understand the logic behind calling `rootfs_mount()` from
>   `start_kernel()`, as it is not mounting any filesystem.

Well, `mount_nodev()` does not mean *it is not mounting any filesystem*, but rather (see [VFS - The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt)):

> mount_nodev: mount a filesystem that is not backed by a device

(for example NFS). By the way, this is also reflected in `/proc/filesystems`.
`rootfs_mount()` in particular mounts the *ramfs* or *tmpfs*.

Addendum - This [Linux Initialization HOWTO](http://en.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux-Init-HOWTO-5.html#ss5.1) says about the call in `start_kernel()`:

> #### vfs_caches_init(mempages)
>
> (in linux/fs/dcache.c)
>
> Call kmem_cache_create() to create
>   slab caches for buffer_head, names_cache, filp, and for CONFIG_QUOTA,
>   dquot.
>
> Call dcache_init() to create the dentry_cache and
>   dentry_hashtable.